# Azure AppInsights data export

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights

How can I export data from Azure AppInsights?  I know there is Continuous Export feature which I configured a few hours ago.  However, I need to export the data that Azure stored before I configured this feature. I need at least the last 4-5 days.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Application Insights blade click on the Metrics Explorer button in the toolbar.

[image]

In the toolbar of the Metrics Explorer blade is an Export button. More information is available [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-insights-metrics-explorer/#export-to-excel).

Comment: Is little sad. I hope in future MS will implement switch button to select if user want to or do not want to export historical data in retention period inside continuous export feature settings.

Comment: Metrics explorer experience is for slicing and dicing data and not so much for getting raw information like you get in export. Search provides a closer experience. It is definitely not as useful as what you get via continuous export.

Answer (score 1):

Last 7 days of data is available from Search blade on AI portal. Unfortunately there is no simple way to export all of your data before the export was configured, but you may try capturing responses via fiddler from your search blade and clean up the responses yourself to get the raw data.